# Posting an Item on E-commerce website via SMS message

Tags: web, sms, e-commerce

We have a project to create an ecommerce website for Filipino Farmers, but the catch is to integrate SMS messages; Use the SMS messaging to post a sale or deal on the website. Is there a way to possibly do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this aproach

FARMER -> SMS -> SMS GATEWAY -> YOUR PROGRAM - ECOMMERCE WEBSITE (API/DB)

- Farmer Send SMS
- SMS is received by an SMS Gateway (try to google this)
- Your Program read incoming SMS from SMS Gateway
- Your Program read the SMS, then translate what it means, (e.g. posting sales)
- Depend on the SMS instruction, your program then communicate to Ecommerce Website through certain API, or simply add it directly into website database.

Comment: Thanks, will look that up

Comment: What language and frameworks should we use?

Comment: try from what you already can, if it is possible. e.g. if you currently do java, try to do using java. if you currently use C++ try using C++.